# How do you get 57 points on an answer?

Tags: support, reputation

See here
https://stackoverflow.com/users/573261/cyberkiwi?tab=reputation

At the moment, the top post there is
[Why is sqlpsx not included in SQL Server itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778032/why-is-sqlpsx-not-included-in-sql-server-itself#4778051)

The answer has 5 upvotes and was accepted.  How did it get 57?  Is it anything to do with "the answer is 42" + 15 (accepted)??

Comment: Looks like you hit the reputation cap.

Comment: by adding Heinz catsup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely scenario is that your reputation was capped by hitting the 200 mark, but you had also accrued one downvote prior to that 5th upvote. This will make it only worth 2 reputation, to counter the earlier downvote. So +40 for the first 4 votes, +2 for the last one, and +15 for the acceptance yields +57.

You can confirm for yourself the exacts of how this played out using a [reputation audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation).

Comment: Seems to be a plausible scenario, certainly. It's worth noting for the OP's sanity that he can still earn the +15 for accepted answers even after hitting the rep cap. So upvotes won't get him anything until midnight UTC (except the feeling of having contributed to a better world, certainly), but accepts certainly will.

Comment: @Simon I did check to see that the users were the same, just to let you know. ♪ That's also why the reputation audit link is specifically to Stack Overflow rather than a demonstration.

Comment: I think you meant /reputation in your link.  I got it, it shows one row with `4778051 [1]`.  But that would be 56 not 57... cue forward to daily recalc in 3,2...

Comment: +1 because it's probably the right answer in this case as opposed to my generic answer.

Comment: @Anthony - `for the OP's sanity` - weird feeling being referred to in 3rd person form while still in the room

Comment: @cyberkiwi I did mean to add /reputation, yes (thanks, Robert). Now, it *is* more accurate there, though, so if you were to run your daily recalc, you will probably see your graph update to only say +56. This would then be due to casting a downvote, rather than receiving one.

Comment: @ChrisF Oh, what irony it is that I am capped for the day and have gotten 0 for this, haha ♪

Answer (score 3):

The machine that answered the question told you to ask the right question.

Since the points is 57 for the question, then the answer is not 42, but the answer to the answer is 42.

Meaning that you found the right question that gives the right answer.

Congratulations. You validated that monkeys banging on a keyboard can eventually write Romeo and Juliet.

You also broke the universe.

Virus = very yes!

Comment: I like the answer even if it is very wrong and even gets the facts wrong.

Comment: I wish to put this answer in a locket and keep it with me always.

Answer (score 2):

You hit the rep cap (200 points from votes).

If you were at 193 points for the day (say) then the last up-vote from 4 to 5 would only give you 7 points rather than the full 10.

It's a bit more complicated than that due to the points from answer acceptances not counting towards the cap, but that's basically it.

Comment: that's hard to calculate then. It would seem safer that the system would forward the points to the next day. Otherwise recalcs would have to understand what day points were rewarded on.

Comment: @Xaade - points aren't carried over, they're just lost. The system **does** know when (as measured against UTC) votes were cast and hence points awarded. That information is used for other things as well (vote fraud detection for example).

Comment: If points were forwarded, some users could stop *now* and continue to accrue points through 2094.

Comment: You mean like Shakespeare?